# too long text in textview - show only ending part

Tags: android, textview

I've got a TextView. When multi-line text inside is short and fit to available space I set gravity to top:

```
tv.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
```

When the text is longer than space in TV I'd like to show only the end of text by:

```
tv.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/textLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:text="Long text bla bla."
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="37sp" />

       ...

    </RelativeLayout>
```

What is the simplest solution to check if text (in many lines) is longer than available space (I don't want to hardcode number of lines because size is different for different screens)? Is there any indicator?

Comment: post your layout where you use textview.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds

Comment: @minhaz, I've seen this before, but I don't believe that this is the simplest solution ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try put `TextVew` in `LinearLayout` and compare textview height with linearlayout height.

Like this

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/textLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" >

<LinearLayout 
        android:id ="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:text="Long text bla bla."
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="37sp" />
```

To compare between theme :

```
if(text.getHeight()>linear.getHeight()){
            //Here TextView longer than available space
        }
```

Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than changing the `gravity` in order to force display of the end of the text, I suggest that you use ellipsis with the dots at the start so that the end of your text will display.

**Example**:

```
    <TextView
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="Long text bla bla."
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="37sp" />
```

You may also end up choosing some of the other `android:ellipsize` options such as "`middle`" and "`marquee`". See: [TextView:android:ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is good idea, but doesn't fit to my requirements.